# Condition Zero game "HD Models" option makes no difference at all

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-condition-zero

I have Condition Zero game installed using Steam. I also have Counter Strike 1.6

Both game have this option named "Enable HD Models if available:

[image]

**But it doesn't make any change at all in Czero.**

The same option in Cstrike changes the models. If you uncheck it, it uses classic models. If you check it, you see new models.

---

When I browsed local files in steam folder, I noticed these things:

[image]

[image]

So **why I think** it works for **Cstrike** is because there's a folder named "cstrike_hd" and it contains player models inside it (probably those are new models). If it has to use classic models, it just locates inside "cstrike" folder.

But we don't see any folder named like "czero_hd". Probably that's why Czero is using the default models as HD models and there's no way it "understands" any classic models.

---

**Given all that, is it a bug in the game or it has always been like that? If yes, any way to fix it?**

Personally, it doesn't make sense to me that you have the option of HD Models and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: The option says "if available". As a software developer, it's not uncommon to create configs like this just in case some day they _do_ become available and we decide to release them in a upgrade/expansion/dlc/mod.

Answer (score 1):

As Roddy theorized, this option is a leftover from an engine update: Gearbox's "High Definition Pack" update for Half-Life.

As for CZ: **yeah, the option never changed anything**. Little fun-fact as well is that the "HD models" in CS 1.6 are actually CZs models.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the 1st statement? I'm not much aware of engine and half life. That would be really helpful. Looks like you have the answer but I want to understand it fully.

Comment: @Vikas "engine" refers to the "game engine" in this case.  The original Counter Strike and Half-Life video games both used the same game engine ([GoldSrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoldSrc)), which means they share a lot of the same features essentially.  It's very common for game developers to use the same game engine for multiple games they develop (Valve developed both Half-Life and Counter Strike).

Comment: @TimmyJim I just read Wikipedia page about Condition Zero. Gearbox delelopers were also involved in it. So clearly it also uses same GoldSrc engine. But I don't get Leo's statement "leftover from an engine update". Engine is still same so what is this update? The statement is a bit confusing/complex to understand for me.